# Get value from list item on ol list click function

Tags: javascript, jsp

I need to get value form every list click

Here is my list:

```
<c:forEach items="${cmlist}" var="records"> 
   <ol class="dd-list"  id="chapterlist" >
      <li id="cs" class="dd-item" data-id="1" value="${records.levelID}">
         <div class="dd-handle">
            <a href="#subchaptercontent">Chapter:  ${records.levelName}</a> 
         </div>
      </li>
   </ol>
</c:foreach>
```

here is my click function code:

```
$(window).load(function(){
   $("#chapterlist li a").on("click", function(){
      level =  $(this).parent('li').val();
      console.log("level"+level);
   });
});
```

Could you please help?

Comment: Your js and html are not seems relevant. Provide jsfiddle, or update your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`parent()` function only goes up one level of DOM, so it gets to your `<div>` element and stops there. Use `parents()` instead.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vnu6h/1/)

Note, that `val()` will only work if value is an integer. Shouldn't be a problem with an ordered list, though, where value is the number of an item.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the `value` method to get the `value` attribute of this object.
Please, update your jsp by

```
 <c:forEach items="${cmlist}" var="records">    
                                <ol class="dd-list"  id="chapterlist" >
                                    <li id="cs" class="dd-item" data-id="1" data-value="${records.levelID}"><div class="dd-handle"><a href="#subchaptercontent">Chapter:  ${records.levelName}</a> </div>


   </li></ol></c:foreach>
```

And your javascript by

```
level =  $(this).parent('li').data('value');
```

[**Fiddle to test this solution**](http://jsfiddle.net/s36b6/)

Comment: sorry ,now also not getting value,In console only printing undefined

Comment: $(this).parents('li').val(); I have use this one and got the value.Instead of parent use parents ,Thank you for your comments Paul Rad-Dupuy